# How do I read project files under the Shared project in a Windows Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Namely, a file that lives here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19417676/snowbird_confusion.png (image linked due to lack of reputation to post directly)

Tutorials and documentation encourage the use of `Windows.Storage` namespace, but when when running my project and enumerating every file and folder in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData`, it's revealed that nothing exists in there. Furthermore, nothing exists in the Local, Roaming or Temp folders either.

Using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation` gets me close, but it puts me in the `...\Debug\AppX` directory. When viewing the built project structure, the actual folder containing my .rtf file lives in `...\Debug\Tales`, and WinRT applications are very restrictive about walking directory structures (not to mention it probably wouldn't be portable to the Windows Phone anyway).

So, how do I access this file?

Comment: Are there any other copies throughout the AppX folder? Also, have you tried ignoring the 'shared namespace' and just referring to it as if the folder were in the main project? So if your shared folder is `/Images`, just refer to it as `/Images/Filename.Ext`.

Comment: Solved it (as expected, shortly after asking the question...). Will post my solution once the timer expires. Essentially, I'd forgotten to change my Build Action to Content on the file itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I had correctly set my .rtf file to `Copy to output dir: Copy Always`, but had forgotten to change its `Build Action` to `Content`.

The below code now works just fine.

```
StorageFolder folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("MyFolder");
StorageFile file= await folder.GetFileAsync("MyFile.rtf");
string rtfString = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
```